# How to get IConfiguration in Azure Timer function in .Net 5

Tags: azure-functions, .net-5

I need to get the IConfiguration in .Net 5 isolated process Azure functions to ConfigureServices using DI. How can I do this?

```
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
        .ConfigureServices(s => { 
            // Get IConfiguration
            // Configure services based on config settings
        })
        .Build();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`ConfigureServices(Action<HostBuilderContext, IServiceCollection> configureDelegate)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostbuilder.configureservices?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) overload.

That way, you can access the [`HostBuilderContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuildercontext?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) that contains the `IConfiguration` (as well as the `IHostEnvironment` if needed).

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, s) =>
    { 
        // Get IConfiguration
        var configuration = hostBuilderContext.Configuration;

        // Configure services based on config settings
           
    })
    .Build();
```

You can also customize the configuration if needed, via the [`ConfigureAppConfiguration(Action<HostBuilderContext, IConfigurationBuilder> configureDelegate)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostbuilder.configureappconfiguration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) method:

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configBuilder) =>
    {
        configBuilder
            .AddJsonFile("custom-settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            ;
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, s) =>
    { 
        // Get IConfiguration
        var configuration = hostBuilderContext.Configuration;

        // Configure services based on config settings
           
    })
    .Build();
```

Comment: You can skip `ConfigureAppConfiguration` and `AddCommandLine` inside `ConfigureAppConfiguration` as they are already added when you call `ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults`

Comment: Good point, I'll remove those to avoid any confusion that they're required.